# JPQL handling null values

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Suppose i have the following scenario:

I have an entity `Person` with attributes  `firstName` and `lastName`. Whenever i get a new object `Person` i want to check whether this person is already in my database. So i check with this `@NamedQuery`:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAlreadyExisting", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstname = :firstName and p.lastname = :lastName")`

But as it turns out, `firstName` can be `null` and thus JPQL searches for the String `null` as the content of the column `firstName` and of course doesnt find any results.

So my question is, how can I bypass this (unwanted) behaviour, i.e. how do i specify whether i want it to search for the object `null` or string `null` without checking every single entry for being `null`.

Comment: Check for "name IS NULL OR name = :firstName" perhaps? like you would in SQL

Comment: Isnt there an easier way of accomplishing this? What if the entity has a lot ( > 100 ) columns and connections and references to other entities? That's a lot of effort for a ( comparatively ) trivial problem.

Comment: That syntax is what the JPQL model defines (see the JPA spec). I think DataNucleus JPA caters for parameters with value null passed in and adjusts the generated SQL as a result, but if you aren't using that JPA implementation then its no "solution" for you

Comment: `SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE (p.firstname = :firstName OR :firstName IS NULL) and (p.lastname = :lastName OR :lastName IS NULL)`